# "Error loading USE or USELSX module: *RFC": what is the required registry key?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, saprfc, sap-r3

My PC was updated from Notes 8.5.3 to Notes 9, and I don't know how it was done (upgrade or full uninstall 8 then reinstall 9).  All that I know is that since then, I the the following error in a few agents:

> Error loading USE or USELSX module: *RFC

We are indeed using the old SAP R/3 connector.  I have the DLLs, but I noticed the registry key wasn't there anymore (see this page for reference: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_USELSX_STATEMENT.html ).

Anyone knows what the registry key should be?  I tried the following, without success :

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, SOFTWARE, Lotus, Components, LotusScriptExtensions, 2.0, RFC, whose value points to my Notes program folder.

Thanks

Comment: The page that you linked indicates that a reference to the LSX file can be in the registry or in the notes.ini file. Do you have a backup copy of your notes.ini file from before the upgrade?

Comment: ftp://ftp.lotus.com/pub/lotusweb/eibu/spxlsxwp.pdf and search for the word 'entry'. It suggests to use a utility that comes with the SAP dlls. Hope this helps.

Comment: Richard: the section in  the Notes.ini file is for Windows 3.1, before the registry existed.  And I can't get the registry key to work (or I am missing something else).

D.Bugger: I don't have the original install package, nor such a folder

Comment: Turns out the admins still had the install kits, si I just reinstalled and the registry was fixed.  See answer for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone needs the info, RFC needs to be added as a string value (and not a new key) in  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, SOFTWARE, Lotus, Components, LotusScriptExtensions, 2.0, and the value of the string must be the path to the dll (default installation folder is c:\Lotus\LSXR3\Nlsxrfc.dll).